# Disable DML execution from GCP console

Tags: dml, google-cloud-spanner

Is there way to enable/disable DML execution for google cloud spanner through GCP console. With service admin access, people can execute **INSERT** or **DELTE** statements. Want to disable it except READ access with **SELECT** mostly in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/iam#roles

As documented, this predefined IAM role "roles/spanner.databaseReader" grants the users read-only access to a database.